# How can every finite lattice be complete?

Tags: lattice-orders

Suppose I have an antichain $\{a,b\}$ and I form this into a poset $P = \{a,b,\top,\bot\}$ so that $a \le \top$, $b \le \top$, $\bot \le a$ and $\bot \le b$. I believe this forms a lattice.

So far so good. Now, it is known that every finite lattice is complete, which means that every subset of that lattice is also a lattice. Suppose I form the subset $S = \{a,b\}$. My formula doesn't work anymore because $\top \notin S$ and $\bot \notin S$, so it seems like my sublattice doesn't meet the requirement, which makes me think my poset P isn't a lattice either. What am I misunderstanding?

- Is it OK for $a \vee b = \top$ when $\top \notin S$?
- Or have I misunderstood the definition of lattice, finite lattice, or complete lattice; or is it not the case that every finite lattice is complete?

Comment: Why do you think every subset of a complete lattice is a lattice?

Comment: @IttayWeiss because every finite lattice is complete... and doesn't the completeness mean that every subset is also a lattice?

Comment: That did not answer my question.

Comment: Ahhh, the edit explains it. No, complete lattice is a poset where every subset has a meet.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I remain confused. What am I misunderstanding, the definition of lattice, complete lattice, finite, or poset?

Comment: Complete lattice.

Comment: @IttayWeiss So, per the question, P gives me a finite lattice that is not complete?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Or, if P is a lattice, is it the case that the meet of items from the subset can be an element from the containing set P instead?

Comment: If $x,y$ are in a sublattice $S$ of $P$, in particular, $x \land y \in S$ and $x \lor y \in S$. We must have closure under both operations.

Comment: $a \lor \bot = a$, not $\top$, as you claim in line 2. The only meet equal to $\top$ is $a \lor b$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm not exactly sure how to reword the question to satisfy you (other than to remove the "because" of why I think this forms a lattice) but the question remains: is P a lattice (and I have misunderstood what complete or finite lattice implies) or is P not a lattice because I have misunderstood what that means?

Comment: $P$ is a lattice, but your reason is stated sloppily.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma OK... so I'll remove that. Now, would you be interested in helping me understand what I'm not understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that $P$ is a lattice. And a finite lattice is (trivially) complete.

What $P$ *complete* means here is that every subset of $P$ has a meet and a join in $P$. This certainly holds for your subset $S$, which has meet $\top$ and join $\bot$.

A subset $S \subseteq P$ is a sublattice if $\forall x,y \in S: x \land y \in S, x \lor y \in S$. $S$ should be closed under the lattice operations meet and join (like subgroups in groups, subspaces in vector spaces etc.). Also, $\top \in S$ and $\bot \in S$ must hold (neutral elements must lie in the substructure too).

So your $S$ is certainly not a sublattice of $P$. And complete does *not* imply that every subset is a sublattice. It's not even true that a sublattice of a complete lattice is itself a complete lattice (linear orders already suffice to show this, consider $\mathbb{Q}$ inside $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Thank you for your patience helping me understand this!

Comment: @DanielLyons You're welcome. It's always good to become intimate  with the definitions at the first stage of studying a subject. Study many examples!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I don't get why every finite lattice is trivially complete. My doubt is that definition of lattice ensures existence of meet and joins for every pair of elements in poset. But why should that imply that every subset have meet and join.

Comment: I have just read the definitions of complete lattice from wikipedia and from this page itself.

Comment: @VimalPatel by induction, from sips of pairs we get sips of finite sets by transitivity. Just like we have finite sums in any additive group etc.

Comment: I got slight idea from your last comment.(I'm new to this topic and studying this on my own.So my question may seem bit silly.). Can we use procedure like selecting arbitrary pair of element from subset and then replacing it(removing both and including meet of both into consideration) by it's meet then repeating  that procedure until we're left with single element which will be meet of our subset. And this procedure terminates because subsets are finite. Does that work?

Comment: @VimalPatel yes, that’s one way to do it in practice. The order does not matter as $a \land b = b \land a$ etc.